# Failed to create directory error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I'm new to both Node.js and Tensorflow so I apologize if this is kind of stupid. I'm also new to Stack Overflow so I apologize if this isn't the best-formatted question. I'm trying to implement Tensorflow into a Discord bot(to make a chatbot). I have some experience in Java so I was able to fix some node.js errors, but I can't figure out what this error means as it appears to be a Tensorflow error, not a node.js error and I'm completely new to Tensorflow. One more thing: I am using the provided example code found at https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/nodejs except for `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'` which I replaced with `const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');` since ***import*** gives an error.

The error I am getting:

`2020-03-25 21:02:38.317965: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:57 : Not found: Failed to create a directory: \/tmp; No such file or directory
(node:3504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid TF_Status: 5
Message: Failed to create a directory: \/tmp; No such file or directory
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.executeMultipleOutputs (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:206:43)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.createSummaryFileWriter (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:1580:14)
    at Object.summaryFileWriter (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\tensorboard.js:98:17)
    at TensorBoardCallback.ensureValWriterCreated (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:310:40)
    at TensorBoardCallback.logMetrics (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:296:22)
    at TensorBoardCallback.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:262:26)
    at step (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:61:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:42:53)
    at C:\Users\BCG04\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\callbacks.js:36:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
(node:3504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:3504) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

This is the code with the error:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    //Start TENSORFLOW tests

    const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [200] }));
model.compile({
  loss: 'meanSquaredError',
  optimizer: 'sgd',
  metrics: ['MAE']
});


// Generate some random fake data for demo purpose.
const xs = tf.randomUniform([10000, 200]);
const ys = tf.randomUniform([10000, 1]);
const valXs = tf.randomUniform([1000, 200]);
const valYs = tf.randomUniform([1000, 1]);


// Start model training process.
async function train() {
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    epochs: 100,
    validationData: [valXs, valYs],
    // Add the tensorBoard callback here.
    callbacks: tf.node.tensorBoard('/tmp/fit_logs_1')
  });
}
train();

    //End TENSORFLOW  tests
    console.log('Ready!');
    console.log("Servers:")
    client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => {
        console.log(" - " + guild.name)

        // List all channels
        client.guilds.cache.map((channel) => {
            console.log(` -- ${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}`)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Message: Failed to create a directory: \/tmp;  looks like you are running in windows box and definitely /tmp will not be available. If you an share code snippet, i think community can help.

Comment: I updated it with the code with the error. Sorry, I don't really know how to format it good for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for updating with snippet and sorry for delay in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running on windows machine, this directory is invalid.

Please replace this line `callbacks: tf.node.tensorBoard('/tmp/fit_logs_1')` with this

```
callbacks: tf.node.tensorBoard('C:\\Users\\BCG04')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have access to create `tmp` folder on root as indicated on the code `tf.node.tensorBoard('/tmp/fit_logs_1')`. Try to change the path.

For me i've change it into `tf.node.tensorBoard('.tmp/fit_logs_1')` so it will create `.tmp` directory on current working path.